# Reordering bar plots - R, ggplot, position = "dodge"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a data frame using the following code:

```
> p <- rep(c("5e-8", "0.05", "1"), 2)
> pgc1_rsq <- c(0.0037, 0.0726, 0.0847)
> meta_rsq <- c(0.0263, 0.1829, 0.1753)
> values <- c(pgc1_rsq, meta_rsq)
> Type <- c(rep("PGC1", 3), rep("PGC meta-analysis", 3))
> mydata <- data.frame(p, values)
> mydata$p <- factor(mydata$p, levels = c("5e-8", "0.05", "1"))
```

I created a bar graph using the following code:

```
> plot <-ggplot(mydata, aes(p, values))
> plot +geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge") + xlab("P-value threshold") + ylab("Proportion of variance explained (Nagelkerke Rsq)")
```

Which produced this plot:
[image: Bar plot]

I would now like to re-order the bars - so that "PGC1" comes before "PGC meta-analysis" in each pair. I have tried making both "values" and "Type" factors and ordering levels with PGC1 coming first like this:

```
> mydata$value <- factor(mydata$value, levels = c("pgc1_rsq", "pgc_meta"))
```

But this gave me an error message with "Type" and did not produce the desired outcome with "values".

Input and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not include `Type` in your `dataframe`:

```
p <- rep(c("5e-8", "0.05", "1"), 2)
pgc1_rsq <- c(0.0037, 0.0726, 0.0847)
meta_rsq <- c(0.0263, 0.1829, 0.1753)
values <- c(pgc1_rsq, meta_rsq)
Type <- c(rep("PGC1", 3), rep("PGC meta-analysis", 3))
mydata <- data.frame(p, values,Type)
mydata$Type <- factor(mydata$Type, levels = c("PGC1","PGC meta-analysis"))
mydata$p <- factor(mydata$p, levels = c("5e-8", "0.05", "1"))

plot <-ggplot(mydata, aes(p, values))
plot +geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge") + xlab("P-value threshold") + ylab("Proportion of variance explained (Nagelkerke Rsq)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try factoring fill within geom_bar:

```
plot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(p, values))
plot + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = factor(Type, levels = c("PGC1", "PGC meta-analysis"))), position = "dodge") + 
xlab("P-value threshold") + 
ylab("Proportion of variance explained (Nagelkerke Rsq)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up your dataframe a bit

```
mydata <- data.frame(p = factor(rep(c("5e-8", "0.05", "1"), 2), levels = c("5e-8", "0.05", "1")), 
                 values =c(0.0037, 0.0726, 0.0847, 0.0263, 0.1829, 0.1753), 
                 Type = factor(c( rep("PGC meta-analysis", 3),rep("PGC1", 3)), levels = c("PGC1", "PGC meta-analysis")))



ggplot(mydata, aes(p, values))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge") + 
  xlab("P-value threshold") + 
  ylab("Proportion of variance explained (Nagelkerke Rsq)")
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all great answers. The most elegant way to do it uses the very useful `gather` from `tidyr`. A must in most `ggplot`s

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(p = c("5e-8", "0.05", "1"),
           `pgc1_rsq` = c(0.0037, 0.0726, 0.0847),                    # change names here
           `pgc_meta` = c(0.0263, 0.1829, 0.1753)) %>% 
  gather(Type, Value, 2:3) %>% 
  mutate(Type = factor(Type, levels = c("pgc1_rsq", "pgc_meta"))) %>% # and here if you need
  ggplot(aes(x = p, y = Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  xlab("P-value threshold") + 
  ylab("Proportion of variance explained (Nagelkerke Rsq)")
```

Comment: probably worth introducing `tidyverse` since three of the packages are being used.

Comment: I prefer not to clog my namespace, especially in learning environments such as this, but to each their own.